# How to bring imageView in front of cardview ? When both are of Relative Layout childs

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-elevation

I have a layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff6da"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vats.vatishs.cardviewprogrammatically.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hello I am a text View." />

        </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/select_delete_chim" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which works fine. The result will be a image view above frame layout but when I use the following xml in which i have replace frame layout with CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff6da"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vats.vatishs.cardviewprogrammatically.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hello I am a text View." />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:background="@drawable/select_delete_chim" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then the result will be: ImageView at the back of CardView.

Any Solution for this?

One thing more, It will work fine on pre-lollipop devices but on lollipop it doesn't work.

[Output with CardView on pre-lollipop devices (required output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPf9e.png)

[Output with CardView on lollipop devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTZvs.png)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

CardView has default elevation which is greater than ImageView, So we have to add greater elevation in ImageView than CardView's elevation.

e.g. `imageView.setElevation(10);` and `cardView.setElevation(5);`

Now, its working fine on all devices.

Comment: You can also do the above in your xml as follows: android:elevation="10dp" for your ImageView and card_view:cardElevation="5dp" for your CardView.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this attr

```
  app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

to the CardView in XMl .

Like this

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

This will make other view in Front of `CardView`

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It will bring the `ImageView` to front.

Comment: Add elevation as "0dp".

Comment: i don't want that imageView will become a child of cardView, because imageView is a cross icon which I have to display at the corner of cardview in such a way that it appears 1/4th in cardView and rest outside of cardView.

Comment: edited the ans. The imageView to be in separate cardview with transparent background. And you can place it wherever is required.

Comment: I want to place it halfly above cardview and halfly outside cardview. So it is not possibe by addind imageview in cardview.

Comment: If you want to place a view half on elevation(CardView) and half without elevation, How will it be possible? To place something on elevated surface, the view has to be elevated only.

Comment: check out the attached images

Answer (score 2):

Write this line in your java code after initializing the `ImageView`.

`imageView.bringToFront();`

Comment: nothing special in code, there is just onCreate() method in which i have called setContentView()

Comment: The main problem is that It should work on all devices but not on lollipop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete answer to your question 
You can wrap CardView with a FrameLayout and put an ImageView outside of the CardView's parent like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <FrameLayout...>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView...>
            <Content/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

alternatively here is the Java code that supports Android versions below and after lollipop

```
image.bringToFront();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     image.setElevation(10);
}
```

this will bring the image to the front

Answer (score 2):

Adding just `app:cardElevation="-1dp"` to the `CardView` in your xml will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Write Image view Above cardview,hopefully it solve the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff6da"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vats.vatishs.cardviewprogrammatically.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
        android:src="@drawable/select_delete_chim" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hello I am a text View." />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, It doesn't works. Even my first xml i.e frame layout will fail if i change image view position in xml

Comment: and also use src instead of background

Answer (score 0):

CardView  ->  app:cardElevation ="4dp"

ImageView ->  android:translationZ="6dp"

Send the CardView to the back.

Comment: If your card and imageview is same position then card will cover the imageView. So if you pull the imageView over cardview as using translationZ then you will see result. Also if you do not want to use elevation then increase just translationZ value.

Answer (score 0):

this will work.

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/volume"
            android:translationZ="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </FrameLayout>
```