# How to bring view in front of cardview?

Tags: android, xml

I have one design pattern, but i'm not sure how could i create this. This is how it should looks:

[image]

I'm still struggling with putting image view in front of cardview. Any thoughts about that or example how this could be done? Thanks!

This is what i have done:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/containor"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_profile"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/soccer_player"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card_review">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nije lose"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: in frame layout and relative layout, layouts added last are on top. so just change the order in which you are writing them. and provide your parent layout too in question if shifting the order doesn't work

Comment: Maybe this link could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523871/how-to-bring-imageview-in-front-of-cardview-when-both-are-of-relative-layout-c

Answer (score 6):

You need to give a higher `elevation` for your ImageView.
Try the following for example...

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(findViewById(R.id.iv_profile),yourCardView.getElevation() * 2);
```